# How to schedule a stored procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, scheduled-tasks

How do I schedule a stored procedure in Sql Server 2005 that it runs once at the start of every month (and on database startup)?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You will need to [create a job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186273.aspx) using the [SQL Server Agent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx).

Comment: Can you expand this answer with information from the linked articles?

Answer (score 27):

In SQL Server Management Studio, go expand the **SQL Server Agent** node under the DB server, right click the **Jobs** folder and select **New Job...**

[image: SQL Server Agent -> Jobs -> New Job]

<sup>(If the SQL Server Agent node does not appear, [you may be missing the required permissions](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25192/124239))</sup>

That will take you through a wizard to schedule a sproc to run  on whatever schedule you want.

In terms of how to get a sproc to run on db startup, see [this article](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/08/14/60280.aspx).

Comment: maybe a picture would help. I don't see `the SQL Server Agent node under the DB server`

Comment: Turns out I may not have permission to view it http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25192/could-not-find-the-server-agent-in-ssms