# Executing a stored procedure every hour by using the .net code

Tags: .net, sql, stored-procedures

How can I execute a stored procedure every one hour by using .net code?

(Stored procedure should be executed automatically for every one hr)

Comment: Use an sql server job. They are meant for such tasks

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use a SQL job? If not, you probably want a service rather than a .NET app - since a service will be automatically started on startup and will be transparent to the user

Comment: You could just use and app and use the windows scheduler to run it every hour.   Or sql server jog as recommeneded above.

Comment: @All, Am ready to use .net or sql code to complete this task. Thank You.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342935/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Create a SQL Server Agent job](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx)

.net processes are too expensive in terms of memory for such tasks.

If you really need to run a .net application, look out for scheduled tasks.
Windows task scheduler is good for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to write a [Windows service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464(v=vs.71).aspx) and set it to run every hour.

Calling a stored procedure from c# code can be done [Like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1260952/how-to-execute-a-stored-procedure-from-c-sharp-program).

I haven't posted any code myself becuase I can't find any code in your question as well. A little effort will get you a long way

Answer (score 1):

As commented, best option is to create an SQL agent job. From Microsoft MSDN, to create a SQL Server Agent job:

1. Execute sp_add_job to create a job.
2. Execute sp_add_jobstep to create one or more job steps.
3. Execute sp_add_schedule to create a schedule.
4. Execute sp_attach_schedule to attach a schedule to the job.
5. Execute sp_add_jobserver to set the server for the job.

[More on the subject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181153%28SQL.105%29.aspx)