# How to automatically delete records in sql server after a certain amount of time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have set up temporary user accounts on my sql database where the user names, passwords and date added of my websites users are stored.

I was initially going to have these records delete programmatically but now im wondering if sql server 2008 has a built in function that allows records to be auto-deleted after lets say one day.

This would resolve the issue of a user being able to stay logged into the system after their temporary account is closed

thanks

Comment: you can create procedure which will be delete columns, then create job where you can shedule this procedure exec

Comment: Do not store passwords in plain text.

Comment: You'll need to [Create a Job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268(v=sql.100).aspx).

Comment: You could write an SP that will go through and delete those that are older than a day, then run a job to delete it... I don't know much about either of those things is why I am not answering

Comment: Unfortunately because i am using sql server express i cannot gain access to sql server agent, looks like it may have to be done programmatically

Comment: As the author stated in his comment he's using SQL Server Express and cannot gain access to SQL Server Agent so this is not a duplicate to the Question "MSSQL record date/time auto delete" because the only answer given there is to use SQL Server Agent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to get what you want without actually deleting the records.  You can add a computed column into the table to say whether the record is valid.

```
 IsValid as (case when getdate() - CreatedAt > 1 then 0 else 1 end)
```

You can also do this for key fields in the record, so you cannot find them:

```
_name varchar(255),
name as (case when getdate() - CreatedAt < 1 then _name end)
```

You can then use a view to access the table:

```
create vw_Logins as
    select name, . . .
    from t
    where isValid = 1;
```

Then, at your leisure, you can actually remove the rows if you need to for performance reasons.

EDIT:

You don't actually need a computed column, if you phrase the view as:

```
create vw_Logins as
    select name, . . .
    from t
    where getdate() - CreatedAt < 1;
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why have a computed column when you can just put that in the view?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko . . . You don't.  My thought processes just when down the road of computed columns, before thinking about having a view.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko How would the view work?

Answer (score 17):

You could create a `SQL Job` to run each day and execute a specified stored procedure.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx

Answer (score 7):

you can have your program do it, or set up a [sql agent job](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135739%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi Maslow, can you explain how to set up a sql agent task?

Comment: that's exactly what the link does.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Stored Procedure to do it and then schedule the SPROCs running as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342935/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure).

```
DELETE FROM myTable
WHERE timeStamp < DATEADD(Day, DATEDIFF(Day, 0, GetDate())-1, 0)
```

Comment: hey, i have a stored procedure created but im trying to understand how to set the schedule up in Sql Management studio