# Optimize table to read the most recent rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I have a two tables where we add about 100k and 1.5M new rows every day. These are log entries and in more than 99% of the cases, I'm interested in the last 3 business days when reading.

If I run a simple query like

```
SELECT
0 as Id, ProcessElementName, Null as ModelPath, Status, Remark, ValidFrom, Application, JobID, JobName, CreateDate, CreatedBy, MessageType, Running, Manual, Environment, RunIdentifier, BatchJobGroup, BatchJob, IsTemp, TotalRows = COUNT(*) OVER() 
FROM dbo.pclTB_ProcessElementInfo WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
ValidFrom > '6/26/2017 12:00:00 AM'
AND ValidFrom <= '6/26/2017 11:59:59 PM'
AND (Environment in ('---')) AND
(
Remark LIKE '%' + 'btve' + '%'
AND Application = '---'
AND (IsTemp = 0 OR IsTemp IS NULL )
AND ProcessElementName = '---'
)
ORDER BY JobID ASC
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

it can take up to 10 seconds. There are a few joins in other queries, but most of them are simple.
When I update statistics manually, the execution time goes down to about 2 seconds, but I'm sure there's still room for improvement (I know about trace flag 2371).

What's the best way to optimize a table (or query?) for fetching the most recent rows? Would it maybe make sense to create a new table with just the entries of the most recent X days?

Edit:
This is the index used for the query above

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ProcessElementNameApplicationEnvironmentValidFrom] ON [dbo].[pclTB_ProcessElementInfo]
(
    [ProcessElementName] ASC,
    [Application] ASC,
    [Environment] ASC,
    [ValidFrom] ASC
)
INCLUDE (
    [Status],
    [Remark],
    [JobID],
    [JobName],
    [CreateDate],
    [CreatedBy],
    [MessageType],
    [Running],
    [Manual],
    [RunIdentifier],
    [BatchJobGroup],
    [BatchJob],
    [IsTemp]
    )
    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 80) ON [PRIMARY]
```

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: version sql-server?

Comment: What you are looking for is PARTITIONING.

Comment: @etsa: SQL Server 2012 SP3

Comment: @MarekVitek: I did look into it a few weeks ago but did not pursue the idea more. Do you have a good ressource with more information?

Comment: You can google lot of info on web. I have read documentation on MSDN which is also good. My problem was limitation on what partition function can be.

Comment: First make sure you are using the correct indexes. Look at the Execution Plan to make sure that you are SEEKing the tables, not SCANing.

Comment: @cloudsafe The indexes do seem to be correct. According to the execution plan the index seek takes around 80% of the cost.

Comment: @swift could you tell us what your indexes look like? My point here is that they teach us to make indexes as selective as possible, which implies, that  usually indexes start with timestamp, which is worst possible option for queries like this.

Comment: I also would advice to remove `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint. Not for performance improvement, but as a better practice. Also, could you add execution plan?

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: I did get the occasional deadlock without the hint. Is there another way to circumvent them?

Comment: There are other recommended ways to resolve deadlocks. But that's a bit out of scope for this question.

Comment: OK, one more thing. How is real condition of your query. And how many records it usually returns?

Comment: `Remark LIKE '%' + 'btve' + '%'` and `AND (IsTemp = 0 OR IsTemp IS NULL )` are killers. I'd advice to change your table structure to have `IsTemp` as a not nullable column and replace NULLs with 0. Then you could create filtered index with `IsTemp = 0` condition.

Comment: @MarekVitek: Edited again. The conditions in the brackets are set by the user and can change. If 'ProcessElementName' is set, it returns between 100 and 40k entries.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas: I know that the LIKE is suboptimal, but those are filter conditions set by the enduser. What's the problem with IsTemp?

Comment: I would put `isTemp` as first column in the index. And as Evaldas mentioned the killer here is probably remarks with it's like. Maybe put this column into index too instead of having it in included columns. I don't see any other oportunity here.

Comment: `OR` conditions are generally slow. Having a non nullable column you'd be able to alter your index with condition I've given in previous comment. That would reduce amount of rows you have to read.

Comment: I would move the validFrom field to be the first or second field in the index

Comment: @SteveFord Moving validFrom will usually hurt your performance. It is fine for this query. But isTemp can really help. My estimate is it can shorten time to half. But it depends on distribution of data in that column.

Comment: I'm currently rebuilding the index. Thanks for the moment.

Comment: Regarding Remarks column, I am not sure whether it would be better to have it before ValidFrom or after it.. So you might need to experiment a little with it.

Comment: @MarekVitek: Adding the IsTemp really already halved the execution time. Thank you. I didn't expect, that this would have such a performance impact. I'm now going over all my indexes and will try to maybe add some colums and reorder the ones I have. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can consider table [partitioning](https://www.sqlshack.com/database-table-partitioning-sql-server/). Let's say you will create partition for last 3 days and for the rest of the data. Then you will update your query to use only that specific partition.
It has some limitations like you can partition only by data you use for clustered index, but it might be way.
You don't necessarily have to use different filegroups as mentioned in the link above. Here is another link that might inerrest you. It is about [How to Implement an Automatic Sliding Window in a Partitioned Table on SQL Server 2005](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa964122(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: @Swit will have to confirm if they have Enterprise Edition, or not.

Comment: We have two databases with the Developer Edition and one with the Enterprise Edition.

And to be clear, partitions have to be static and we cannot use a relative date, right?

Comment: Partitions are only available on Enterprise Edition.

Answer (score 1):

When you insert data into the table, insert into another table that save last x day records. And then you can automatically delete records after certain amount of time with stored procedure.
[How to automatically delete records in sql server after a certain amount of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18275386/how-to-automatically-delete-records-in-sql-server-after-a-certain-amount-of-time)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a daily job to recreate filtered indexes. Your existing indexes can be duplicated with the date filtering for the last three days:

```
DECLARE @sql varchar(8000) = '

IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.indexes WHERE name = ''IX_IndexName'')
    DROP INDEX IX_IndexNameON My_table ;

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_IndexNameON My_table (
    timestamp 
)
WHERE timestamp > ''' + CONVERT(varchar(25),DATEADD(d,-3,GETDATE()) ,121) + ''';';

EXEC (@sql);
```