# Getting todays date on WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create an alert to be sent daily. The condition is to display all the Return Orders not completed.
I am expecting it to be sent later today, then just in case there were items on those data that are still not completed by tomorrow, then it will sent out again.

Is there a need to query that condition? let's say

```
SELECT SalesOrderNo, SalesOrderDetailID, CustomerNo, ItemNo, DueDate
  , Completed, Qty, UDCode, CustomerPO 
FROM dbo._EventAlertReturns
WHERE GETDATE() is today?
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Will this work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2342935/how-to-schedule-a-stored-procedure

Comment: Doers "all the Return Orders not completed" have anything to do with today's date? I'm guessing there is simply a completed flag. So for your requirement you do not need to use `getdate()`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're comparing the date value to. Usually, there's a date on the record set (table, temp table, etc) that you want to check, but that doesn't seem to be the case here. Is there a `DateCompleted` field?

Comment: SELECT SalesOrderNo, SalesOrderDetailID, CustomerNo, ItemNo, DueDate
  , Completed, Qty, UDCode, CustomerPO 
FROM dbo._EventAlertReturns alias where alias.DueDate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP       ?     Your question is kinda hard to understand, FYI.

Comment: `getdate()` is a function which returns the current date, so asking if `getdate() = today` (pseudocode) would always evaluate true. Are you trying to check where a given *column* equals the current date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment, your query is adequate on its own, you don't need that WHERE clause - but you cannot set up an automated process using a mere SELECT statement.

As Jon Vote said, to do something like this you need a [SQL Server Scheduled Job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/sql-server-agent?view=sql-server-2017). With a scheduling agent you could create a scheduled package to execute in the evening which emails you the results of your query.

For additional granularity you can look into [SQL Server Data Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017) to more-easily create tasks and settings for your automated packages.